# Is Undetected Chromedriver on Raspberry Pi 4 even doable?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, undetected-chromedriver

Im trying to set up a web scraping bot in Python on my Raspberry Pi 4 using selenium. It works with "ordinary" chromedriver, ex:
"

```
from selenium import webdriver

service = Service(executable_path="/usr/bin/chromedriver")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

driver.get('https//google.com')"
```

The problem is setting up an undetectable chromedriver on the Raspberry Pi to Bypass bots.

I've tried Seleniumbase's UC_driver and also undetected Chromedriver, but end up with: OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error. Granted the drivers permission to run through "CHMOD +x" as well.

I have also tried ordinary chromedriver with options such as:

```
options.add_argument("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
```

Has anyone actually mangage to get an undetectable chromedriver to work on the Raspberry Pi?
On my Windows i have no problems, but seems hard on the RPI.

Tried searching the internet to find the answer, but still no luck.